# Some input/help on this circuit - Looking for advice on various aspects

Tags: ac, adc, signal

Design goals:
I have a 9VAC (1A) power supply. I want to power some microprocessor boards with this, as well as monitor it's signal. (the whole scope is larger, but this portion is isolated to the power supply and interactions with it)

My plan is to rectify the 9VAC into DC (then use DC/DC converters for 5V/3V items). I also want to sample the AC signal with one of the MCPUs, so I need to get it down to ADC levels (0-3.3V)

I put together this simulation on LTSpice, and while it "works" there could definitely be some improvements. (I've also attached it)
[image]

For the rectifier I am planning on using [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/HDS10M-13/8537822). This simulation has a single 4700uF capacitor in it. At a full load current, that will cause a 1.7V ripple. The DC/DC converters I am planning on using are [these](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/AZ1117ID-ADJTRG1/5768489). They shouldn't have a problem with the ripple. I'll use one for 5V and one for 3.3V. However, it's unlikely I will be at full load current. 500-600mA is more realistic, so that would be less ripple.

With regards to the circuit: I use a voltage divider on the 9V RMS signal to get it to 3.3v pk-pk. I understand there are multiple ways to shift this signal up. I decided to go with a summing amplifier. An issue I ran into was the impedances caused by both the 3.3V->1.65V divider and the 9VAC ->1.65V divider. So, I buffered both of them. Finally, using the same [op amp](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ada4522-1_4522-2_4522-4.pdf), I sum them together.

There may be a way to use a single rail, but I just used two rectifiers to get +/-12V to use as the voltages for the op amps. From my reading using a single rail would require doing some other level shifting, and referencing a VCC and a VCC/2 to get it done. I felt like if I already have 12V, then why not use it.

This circuit "works" with some caveats.
The 3.3V output works with some "startup" issues:

[image]

The +/-12V signals work, but I would have expected to see some ripple. Perhaps the sim is limiting that somehow:
[image]

The -12V signal takes 10ms to get going, which is.. strange to me.

Lastly, and this is a concern to me, I have the "grounds" tied together.
The connector coming in is a barrel jack, so I call them "tip" and "ring" on the schematic.
In this sim, "ring" is connected to "ground". I cannot get the simulation to work otherwise.

Definitely welcome suggestions on that.

Thanks for looking!

LTSpice source file is [here](https://pastebin.com/ch7bGzcE)

Clear specific question: Will someone look at this and give me advice on it?

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: "Some input/help on this circuit" is too vague. Please edit you title to ask your actual question.

Comment: Okay, sure. I will do that.

Answer (score 3):

> *Some input/help on this circuit*

- You have "ring" connected to GND. This will short out D4 and D6
- You also have two bridge rectifiers (ignoring D4 being shorted) when, in effect, if you want a positive and negative DC rail, only two single diodes are needed
- You have two AC input nodes with the same name ("9VAC") - that looks problematic because where is the other AC wire coming from and going to?
- I didn't see any DC/DC converters on your schematic

[image]

This is the type of bipolar half-wave rectifier I would consider: -

[image]

Image from [Power Supply Basics for Effects](http://www.geofex.com/Article_Folders/Power-supplies/powersup.htm)

In summary it looks like your rectification method is not very well designed. These are you main problems as I see them. If you use two diodes (not 8) then one AC wire can be GND referenced and it's a simple matter of potting down the other AC wire to a suitable amplitude and adding an offset suitable for measuring/monitoring.

Comment: Thanks.  Rectification isn't something I've dealt with very much and when I decided I wanted both a + and - rail, I just used two rectifiers and "swapped" the outputs.   
I will look at using 2 diodes with a ground reference to try and accomplish what you mentioned.  I'm not seeing it in my mind yet, but LTSpice should help sort that out.

Comment: @jgauthier see the picture I added also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification with the image!